# Efficiently filter ordered file with spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, binary-search

Imagine I have a big log file of the format:

```
Timestamp, text
Timestamp, text
Timestamp, text
Timestamp, text
Timestamp, text
Timestamp, text
```

The log file is already ordered by timestamp.
If I read the file with spark as a dataframe and then filter on timestamp between t1 and t2,
Then he checks for every record if the timestamp is between t1 and t2, which takes a lot of time.

However, is there a way that I can tell spark that the df is already ordered, then it would know it would just have to look for the first and last timestamp, and return all the lines in between, which would be a lot faster?

Comment: The ideal solution would be to partition your input files by your `Timestamp` and then only read in the files that you actually want. Spark supports predicate pushdown, so if you did `spark.read.parquet(myParquet.parq).filter(...)` it would take care of only reading the relevant files for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no such option in spark. But there is different solution, used widely in systems that store events or logs called partitioning. If you have records from many days, add a new column with day only:

```
df.withColumn("day", df.timestamp.cast("date"))
```

then save this file using partitionedBy:

```
df_with_day.write.partitionBy("day").csv("partitioned")
```

This will create directories for every day (and column day will not be saved inside rewritten files), so next query with appropriate `where` filtering will ommit files from directories that are not in range:

```
new_df = spark.read.csv("partitioned")
new_df.where(new.day.between("2016-11-30", "2016-12-10")).show()
```